# Как изменить ссылки

Tags: .htaccess, php, mysql

как изменить ссылки своего сайта? 
щас мой сайт имеет такие ссылки 
site. ru/index.php?option=content&task=view&id=768

а как сделать примерно так

site .ru/id/786-nazvanie-statiy.html

Comment: Предлагаю вам обратить взор в сторону фреймворков... Например CodeIgniter, там отображение ссылок именно такое, какое вы указали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

советую познакомится с [mod rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html), именно то что вам нужно.